# if there is a 3/2 approximation algorithm for independent set then there is a 3/2 approximation algorithm for vertex cover?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, approximation, vertex-cover

if by absurdly there is a 3/2-approximation algorithm for *INDIPENDENT SET* then does there exist a 3/2-approximation algorithm for *VERTEX COVER*?
the implication should be true because independent is reduced to to *VERTEX COVER*, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to prove it.  Don't just assume "it should be true"; write out the proof in detail.  Specify the algorithm for finding a 3/2 approximation for Vertex Cover concretely.  Provide a proof that its output is a 3/2 approximation.

If you try to do that, you should be able to answer your own question for yourself.

Comment: ok but what I ask is whether the implication is true or not in the absurd case that there is an approximation algorithm 3/2 for independent set? is approximability transitive?

Comment: @PatrickBateman, I suggest trying to prove or disprove it, following the approach that I outlined.  If you spend some time on that and get stuck, you can edit the original question to clarify what you are asking and show what progress you've made.